Peak prediction
In my block, I am changing the gain of Amplifier (PGA) in step of +/- 1dB depending on the control voltage derived from the AGC (Automatic Gain Control). But can I change the gain of PGA in one shot itself (like may be deriving it by calculating the control voltage $V_{c}$ with the help of transfer function of the block ??)

Your can change it in whatever steps you like but it's control loop with feedback so you have to make sure that whatever you do remains stable. That's mathematically complicated and I suggest spending some time with a textbook or class on control theory.  For starters look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_theory
